# why custom google api is not sported multiple files search

Tags: google-api

I want to search for MS Word files extension (`.doc` and `.docx`) from Google by API.

How do I get both type of result? This URL is not working fine - it return always doc file type, but not docx return

i wnat to get both type `.doc` and `.docx` at time

```
$url='https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?
key=xxxxxxxx&cx=xxxxxxxxxxx&q='.
urlencode($keywords).'&filetype=docx&filetype=doc';
```